# Can I change the LATNEX RC-S120 ID timeout?

Tags: repeater

I have a LATNEX RC-S120 Simplex Repeater Controller. It IDs by announcement every 15 minutes. Is there any way to modify that setting so it identifies every 10 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Advertisement says:

> ♦️ MAJOR FEATURES
>
> - Up to 3 incoming messages
> - Auto Message is sent out at 15/30/45 minutes
> - …

So, no.